# best way to serialize json android

Tags: java, android, json, serialization, json-deserialization

I'm quite new in android development. I have an app and I'm going with retrofit for the network requests. to handle the response there are some good libraries that I found such as gson , jackson , moshi and som much more. I'm abit confused and I can't decide what I should go with in this particular case. Any help is appreciated.m

Comment: use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson).

Comment: Yes GSON is good with retrofit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a duplicate question. But since you're new to Android development this article will explain everything to you.

https://blog.takipi.com/the-ultimate-json-library-json-simple-vs-gson-vs-jackson-vs-json/

In short , if your json response is quite small, go with gson otherwise Jackson is better.